# How can I get the previous logged events when a particular logger is triggered?

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

I need to show the previous 10 events when a particular logger is triggered. The goal is to show what previous steps occurred immediately before NHibernate.SQL logging was issued.

Currently, I am logging NHibernate sql to a separate file - this is working correctly.

```
<appender name="NHibernateSqlAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\NHibernate.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSqlAppender"/>
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
  <level value="WARN"/>
  <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSqlAppender"/>
</logger>
```

But this only outputs SQL, without context. I would like *all* previous logs within a specified namespace to also be logged, but **only** when the HNibernate.SQL appender is triggered.

I have investigated the use of [BufferingForwardingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender.html) as a means to collect all events, and then filter them within the NHibernateSqlAppender, but this is not working. I have read about the LoggerMatchFilter class, which seems like it is going to help, but I'm not sure where to put it.

```
<appender name="BufferingForwardingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender" >
    <bufferSize value="10" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ALL"/>
    </evaluator>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSqlAppender" />
</appender>

<appender name="NHibernateSqlAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\NHibernate.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />

    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="NHibernate.SQL" />
        <loggerToMatch value="Laan" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="NHibernate" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
    </filter>

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="BufferingForwardingAppender"/>
</root>
```

The idea is that buffering appender will store all events, but then the NHibernateSqlAppender will only flush when an NHibernate.SQL event fires, **plus** it will flush the buffer (of 10 previous items, within the specified logger level, which in this example is Laan.*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement `ITriggeringEventEvaluator` that returns true in the `IsTriggeringEvent()` method when a certain logger (ideally configurable) fires. Have a look a the implementation of the `LevelEvaluator` class, it should be quite easy. The code would look like this:

```
public bool IsTriggeringEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) 
{
    if (loggingEvent == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");
}

    return (loggingEvent.LoggerName == triggeringLoggerName); 
}
```

With this new evaluator your configuration should work though you should remove the filters (I guess).